# MYSQL in XAMPP v3.3.0 is not starting, was running fine till yesterday HY2006 error

Tags: mysql, xampp, innodb, crash-dumps

It was running till yesterday suddenly it's crashing from today morning.
I'm attaching the error log, any help will be appreciated.
I've also tried to find out if any process using up this port with the following command: `netstat -aon | findstr 3306`, but it returns nothing which means port is empty.

```
2022-01-12 11:09:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2022-01-12 11:09:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-01-12 11:09:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-01-12 11:09:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-01-12 11:09:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2022-01-12 11:09:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2022-01-12 11:09:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-01-12 11:09:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2022-01-12 11:09:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2022-01-12 11:09:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp_php8\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-01-12 11:09:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp_php8\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2022-01-12 11:09:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2022-01-12 11:09:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.21 started; log sequence number 10430952; transaction id 13603
2022-01-12 11:09:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp_php8\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2022-01-12 11:09:21 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-01-12 11:09:21 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Everytime I'm running mysql i'm getting this error in the log and the log also gives the same error message, yesterday it was runnig so the log looked a different, I am also sharing yersterday's log:

```
2022-01-11 10:08:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-01-11 10:08:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-01-11 10:08:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-01-11 10:08:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2022-01-11 10:08:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2022-01-11 10:08:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-01-11 10:08:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=10293165
2022-01-11 10:08:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2022-01-11 10:08:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2022-01-11 10:08:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2022-01-11 10:08:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp_php8\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-01-11 10:08:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp_php8\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2022-01-11 10:08:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2022-01-11 10:08:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.21 started; log sequence number 10293174; transaction id 13335
2022-01-11 10:08:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp_php8\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2022-01-11 10:08:59 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-01-11 10:08:59 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Database page corruption on disk or a failed file read of tablespace mysql/transaction_registry page [page id: space=3, page number=0]. You may have to recover from a backup.
2022-01-11 10:08:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Page dump in ascii and hex (16384 bytes):
 len 16384; hex ecefa36b00000000000000000000000000000000000203bc000800000000000000000000000300000003000000000000000900000040000000210000000700000000ffffffff0000ffffffff00000000000100000000009e00000000009e00000000ffffffff0000ffffffff0000000000000000000900000000ffffffff0000ffffffff0000000000010000000200260000000200260000000000000000ffffffff0000ffffffff000000000002aaeaffffffffffffffffffffffffffff000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007f90000000000930fc2000000000090fbc2000000000080000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000930fc200000000c4ab248800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002022-01-11 10:08:59 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: Please remember to add all error messages in text form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally made it work somehow, No I have not unistalled it or re-installed it. It is as of now working fine, the process is given below:

1. Went to C:\xampp_php8\mysql , my xampp mysql's root folder:
2. Renamed **data** folder to **data_blah blah...**
3. Created new **data** folder, copied and pasted all contents of **backup**
   folder in this **data** folder
4. Started xampp, **apache**, **mysql**, went **https://localhost/phpmyadmin**,
   everything works fine here.
5. Stopped xampp, copied only the **database folders** I needed &
   **ib_logfile0,ib_logfile1** and **ibdata1** from old data directory and
   pasted in the new data directory.
6. Started xampp, **apache**, **mysql**, everything seemed fine but INSERT
   privileges were missing.
7. Lastly, pressed **Empty session data** in
   https://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php.

And now everything works fine.